# Dynamically assign ViewController to Navigate

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

In my case I have `UITableView` and have **View all** button for the listing of all the items in separate screens. So I added target for `UIButton` action method in `cellForRowAt`. Now what I am doing in action method:

```
@IBAction func btnViewAllOffer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tblOfferView)
        let indexPath = self.tblOfferView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

        if indexPath != nil {

            if let type = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].type {
                if type == HomeDataType.SponserProduct.rawValue {
                    let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
                    if let title = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].title {
                        vc1.title = title
                    }
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc1, animated: true)
                } else if type == HomeDataType.Offer.rawValue {
                    let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
                    if let title = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].title {
                        vc2.title = title
                    }
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
                } else if type == HomeDataType.BestSeller.rawValue {
                    let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3
                    if let title = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].title {
                        vc3.title = title
                    }
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I need, is there any way I can minimize the code and assign viewcontrollers dynamically so there is no need to instantiate each view controller and push them everytime?
Something like:

```
var vc = UIViewController()
if let type = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].type {
    if type == HomeDataType.SponserProduct.rawValue {
        vc = ViewController1()
    }
    else if type == HomeDataType.Offer.rawValue {
        vc = ViewController2()
    } else if type == HomeDataType.BestSeller.rawValue {
        vc = ViewController3()
    }
}
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to make it safer to handle a situation where vcGeneric might not have been initialised in none of the if/else

Comment: @denis_lor I am trying on your code snippets but it is giving me error

Comment: `if let vcGeneric = vcGeneric {
                    if let title = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].title {
                        vcGeneric.strTitle = title
                    }
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcGeneric, animated: true)
                }`

Cannot assign to property: 'vcGeneric' is a 'let' constant and
Cannot convert value of type 'SimilarViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: Can you try it with the updated code in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `protocol` (SimilarViewController) to define the common properties like `title`:

```
protocol SimilarViewController {
    var title: String? { get set }
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController, SimilarViewController {
    var title: String?
}
class ViewController2: UIViewController, SimilarViewController {
    var title: String?
}
class ViewController3: UIViewController, SimilarViewController {
    var title: String?
}


@IBAction func btnViewAllOffer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tblOfferView)
        let indexPath = self.tblOfferView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

        if indexPath != nil {

            if let type = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].type {
                var vcGeneric: SimilarViewController?

                if type == HomeDataType.SponserProduct.rawValue {
                    vcGeneric = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
                } else if type == HomeDataType.Offer.rawValue {
                    vcGeneric = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
                } else if type == HomeDataType.BestSeller.rawValue {
                    vcGeneric = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3
                }


                if let title = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].title {
                    vcGeneric?.title = title
                }

                if let vcGeneric = vcGeneric  as? UIViewController {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcGeneric, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `extension UIViewController: SimilarViewController {}`?

Comment: @denis_lor why u have if else here can't u use switch case which is more readable in term of code

Comment: @TheCodeTalker I left the code as much similar to the original one as possible, in order to let the person asking the question understand where the issue is. Refactoring is possible but I would suggest to be done outside the scope once the problem is solved

Comment: @denis_lor yes I noticed that exta `let` but I removed from my code.

Comment: Working if I use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcGeneric as! UIViewController, animated: true)` and without extension. I have to type caste vcGeneric

Comment: Try with the latest update I made. `if vcGeneric != nil {` and a safe force-casting  otherwise if you found it working with the comment you provided I might update my answer to leave it correct for others in future

Comment: You can also try to type cast safely like this: 
```if let vcGeneric = vcGeneric  as? UIViewController {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcGeneric, animated: true)
}```

Comment: protocol is one way. the other way is to create a Struct. I have updated that too @Niraj_iOS

Answer (score 0):

**1:** create a struct and assign the value to it.

```
    struct TitleDetails { 
         static var title : String = ""
    }
```

**2:** create an extension of viewController and use it to avoid code repetition.

```
    extension UIViewController {

        func pushVC(_ vcName : String) {
            let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcname)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

**3:** now you can call it directly as,

```
TitleDetails.title = yourTitleValue
self.pushVC("ViewController1")
```

and in your ViewDidLoad() method of your destination view controller,

```
self.title = TitleDetails.title
```

Comment: Thanks @Keshu. But if I want to pass data then?

Comment: @Niraj_iOS do you only need to pass title ?

Comment: title and dataModel array.

Answer (score 0):

Create BaseViewController and derived other ViewController from BaseViewController

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewTitle = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func pushVC(_ vcName : String) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And use below code on ViewController you need like:

```
@IBAction func btnViewAllOffer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tblOfferView)
        let indexPath = self.tblOfferView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

        if indexPath != nil {

            if let type = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].type {
                self.viewTitle = self.homeData[indexPath!.section].title
                if type == HomeDataType.SponserProduct.rawValue {
                    self.pushVC("ViewController1")
                } else if type == HomeDataType.Offer.rawValue {
                    self.pushVC("ViewController2")
                } else if type == HomeDataType.BestSeller.rawValue {
                    self.pushVC("ViewController3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```